# Can't apply custom fonts in css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having a hard time trying to understand what's wrong... I am declaring a simple font face rule:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'my-font';
  url: ('/assets/font.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

I'm declaring it like this:

```
body {
  font-family: 'my-font', monospace;
}

body h1 {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

File structure:

```
index.html
styles.css
assets/
  font.woff2
```

h1 always renders monospace, no matter what the url is.

If I visit `localhost:port/assets/font.woff2` the font gets downloaded correctly by the browser.
If I add a <link ... rel="preload"> the request is made but still doesn't seems to be applied to the document.

I have tested in multiple browsers.

Comment: try this url:
  url: ('../assets/font.woff2') format('woff2');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the declaration.
Try this way :

```
           @font-face {
             font-family: 'MyFont';
             src:  url('./assets/font.woff2') format('woff2'),
        }
```

Comment: In the same way it mysteriously stopped working now testing with other fonts and formats my woff2 started working again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
src: url('./assets/font.woff2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm this?

- The @font-face rule should be added to the stylesheet before any styles, is it?
- The font file is in the root directory of your web page?
- Try 'myFont' not 'my-font'.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Chunkfive;
    src: url('Chunkfive.otf');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for URL of font file.

```
url: ('./assets/font.woff2') format('woff2');
```